# Crear una clase que herede de AppCompatActivity

Tags: android, android-studio

No se si esto será posible, tengo una clase principal que tiene todas las vistas y quiero crear otra que herede dichas vistas.

```
public class Tablero extends AppCompatActivity {

private FrameLayout main;
private Bitmap img;

protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_game);
    main = findViewById(R.id.idVista);
    img = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(), R.drawable.tile_borderland);
}

public void creaTablero (){
    ImageView tile = new ImageView(this); //Aqui lanza una excepción
    tile.setImageBitmap(img);
    main.addView(tile);
}
   }
```

Sin embargo en la instrucción

```
 ImageView tile = new 
 ImageView(this);
```

lanza una excepción

> android.content.Context.getResources()' on a null object reference

cosa que no entiendo por que estoy creando una nueva instancia de ImageView.

Comment: Por cierto si toda la clase la encapsulo en un método dentro de la clase padre, todo funciona correctamente.

Comment: ¿Dónde estas llamando el método `creaTablero()`?, ¿Cuáles son las vistas de cuales quieres heredar, te refieres a crear un CustomView y sobreescribir sus metodos o propiedades?, ¿Cuál es la clase que encapsulas?. Si pudieras aportar mas información quizás podríamos ayudarte con tu problema. Saludos.

Comment: En la clase principal llamo al método creaTablero(), "Tablero t = new Tablero(); t.creaTablero();" Quiero heredar todas las vistas, no quiero sobreescribir nada, solo quiero descargar de código la clase principal..

Comment: El problema aqui es que no debes iniciar o instanciar una actividad de esa manera, ya que las actividades definen un ciclo de vida y estas deben ser iniciadas via Intents. Si lo que quieres es utilizar un método de una actividad desde la actividad que lo crea (segun interpreto tu codigo). Debes iniciar la actividad `Tablero` via intent pasandole un argumento que evalue tu condición y dependiendo de la condición desde la actividad `Tablero`, la evaluas y disparas el método. No se si estas confundido con el término herencia o es que no te entiendo bien. ¿Puedes explicar que intentas hacer?.

Comment: Aqui te dejo la documentación oficial de cómo iniciar una actividad con parámetros (Bundle). https://developer.android.com/training/basics/firstapp/starting-activity?hl=es-419 si tienes problemas con la explicación anterior. Edita tu pregunta, define lo que "Intentas hacer" para emitir una respuesta a tu problema. Intenta ser preciso y con cierto nivel de detalle para poder entender.

Comment: Porque simplemente no insertas draweable en el Imageview

Comment: No tengo ningún problema con los Bundles, Tengo una clase principal, y la clase principal tiene que llamar a un método que se va a ejecutar solo UNA vez, por eso considero que debo crearme otra clase, para no incluir 2000 lineas de código en la clase principal para crear este tablero. El problema viene con la excepción, ¿Porque no me deja instanciar un ImageView, que es un objeto normal y corriente?

Comment: No te deja instanciar un `ImageView` si el `Context` que le pasas es `null`. Al crearlo con la referencia `this` (`new ImageView(this);`), lo que haces es que le pasas la instancia de tu `Activity` y lo convierte en `Context`. Al `Activity` ser `null` porque no se debe instanciar como una clase normal, es decir debe ser iniciada via `Intent` porque tiene su ciclo de vida, el `Context` siempre va a ser `null`. Las vistas no son clases normales como dices, todas estan sujetas a un contexto. Cada `Activity` te representa una pantalla en tu aplicación y todas definen un ciclo de vida.

Comment: Si lo que quieres es mostrar en una pantalla diferente una imagen. Debes iniciar esa `Activity` via `Intent`, favor ver el enlace que te deje en comentarios anteriores. Ahora bien, si lo que quieres es agregar dicha imagen a un contenedor que ya tienes en tu "Clase principal" que pienso que es un `Activity`. Simplemente crea el metodo ahi y agregalo a tu contenedor. Digase a la referencia que quieras agregarlo en tu layout (`LinearLayout, FrameLayout, RelativeLayout`, etc...). No está demás leer un poco la documentación y el ciclo de vida de las `Activity`. Saludos.

Comment: Otra cosa, para crear un ImageView vía código no basta con crear la clase, debes agregar los parámetros iniciales de dicha vista (`LayoutParams`) dependiendo del padre de ella en tu contenedor. En este caso `FrameLayout` porque el ImageView se esta agregando a `main`. Por lo tanto, al agregar la vista a dicho contenedor, debe compartir características propias de quien lo contiene.